# Mui: ImageList with lazy load images

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, imagelist

I am using MUI in my react app and on one of the pages, I am loading a long list of images. I am thinking of lazy loading the images depending on the user page scroll. MUI imagelist just takes a list of images, is there any way to lazy loading images and loading in chunks, rather than a big bang?

Comment: I have never user MUI, but can you listen to scroll event of ImageList? Then when scrollbar is at bottom, dynamically render ImageListItem through array.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try this
react-lazy-load-image-component
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazy-load-image-component